# Как правильно вывести строку через условные теги WordPress и условные операторы?

Tags: php, wordpress, opengraph

Пытаюсь вывести для разметки OpenGraph строки.

Учитывая:

- главную страницу
- 404-ю
- страницу поиска

Конструкция мета тега такая сейчас:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php 

if ( is_front_page() ) {
    echo 'Главная страница';
} 

if ( is_404() ) {
    echo 'Ошибка 404';
} 

if ( is_search() ) {
    echo 'Странца поиска';
} 

else {
    echo the_title();
} ?>

">
```

Проблема следующая :)
На 404-й, странице поиска и остальных страницах всё показывается верно.
А вот на главной выводится не то, что нужно.

На главной показывается мета тег, который содержит и "Главная страница", как надо, и название страницы:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Главная страницаКомпания по производству теплоизоляции">
```

Важно - главная страница сайта у меня статическая (т.е. не блог на главной, а другая страница, выбранная в админке).

**Решение проблемы. Возможно кому-то понадобится.**

В файл functions.php добавить:

```
function og_get_description() {
    switch (true) {
        case is_front_page():
            return 'Главная страница';
        case is_404():
            return 'Ошибка 404';
        case is_search():
            return 'Страница поиска';
        default:
            return get_the_title();
    }
}
```

В header.php добавить вывод:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo og_get_description(); ?>">
```

**Также есть подобное для og:url**

В файл functions.php добавить:

```
function get_cururl() {
    return ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

В header.php добавить вывод:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo get_cururl(); ?>">
```

Comment: Где ты это прописал?

Comment: @SeVlad, конечно в header.php. И оно всё работает, не считая главной страницы...

Comment: @SeVlad, https://radikal.host/i/Jcl98a - вот ссылка на скрин написанного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильный cинтаксис условий .

Если делать в таком стиле, то как-то так:

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    $ogdesc =  'Главная страница';
} 

elseif ( is_404() ) {
    $ogdesc =  'Ошибка 404';
} 

elseif ( is_search() ) {
    $ogdesc =  'Страница поиска';
} 

else {
    $ogdesc =  get_the_title();
}
?>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $ogdesc; ?>">
```

Comment: Кто там заминусовал? Ответ правильный, надо было только get_the_title использовать. Я поправил.

Comment: @KAGGDesign спс. (у меня тут образовалось несколько "доброжелателей"). С функцией по НГ-одей запарке косанул, всё внимание синтаксису условий было :)

Comment: @SeVlad, спасибо, то, что нужно! А почему get_the_title лучше, чем the_title?

Comment: @Andrew функции типа get_* получают данные. Без них - выводят. https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_title

Comment: @SeVlad, и также вопрос. Конструкция для opengraph также имеет meta property="og:url" content="//site.ru/". Проблема в том, что на странице 404 и странице поиска meta og:url пустой. Я пробовал использовать get_permalink() и get_page_link(), всегда пусто в мета теге. Как это исправляется? P.S. про get_the_title понял

Comment: Вообще другой вопрос нужно оформлять отдельно. Но скажу кратко- ни в результатах поиска ни уже тем более на 404 они не нужны. Почитай о сути этой микроразметки.

Comment: @SeVlad, в общем-то, проблему решили так. В functions.php засунул: function get_cururl() { return ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; }. Потом в header.php засунул вызов: <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo get_cururl(); ?>">

Comment: @SeVlad, такой метод помог мне не плодить php-код в шаблоне и всё работает так, как нужно мне :)

Comment: @SeVlad, спасибо за помощь. Resolved